# Kotlin recyclerview only displays cardview a number of data sizes available but not the value or textview

Tags: android, kotlin

I've tried to find the problem within my code. I'm new to kotlin. So basically I want to display a list of arrays into recycler view and card view. So, the recycler view already displays some cardviews based on the number of the data sizes, but still, the textview didn't show up. Is there anyone kotlin developer that could probably help to find what did I miss?
Here's my adapter class:

```
class NotesAdapter(title:List<String>, content:List<String>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<NotesAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
    internal lateinit var titles:List<String>
    internal lateinit var contents:List<String>

    init{
        this.titles = title
        this.contents = content
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): NotesAdapter.ViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.note_item_layout, parent,false)
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: NotesAdapter.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.txtTitle.text = titles.get(position)
        holder.txtContent.text = titles.get(position)
//        holder.cvNote.cardBackgroundColor = holder.view.resources.getColor(getRandomColour(),null)
//        holder?.txtTitle.setText(titles.get(position))
//        holder?.txtContent.setText(contents.get(position))
//        holder?.cvNote.setCardBackgroundColor(holder.view.resources.getColor(getRandomColour(),null))
        val context = holder.txtTitle.context
        holder.view.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(context, DetailNotesActivity::class.java)
            context.startActivity(intent)
        }
    }

    fun getRandomColour(): Int {
        val colours = arrayListOf<Int>()
        colours.addAll(listOf(
                R.color.cornsilk,
                R.color.blanchedalmond,
                R.color.bisque
       ))

        var randomColour = Random
        val number = randomColour.nextInt(colours.size)
        return colours.get(number)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return titles.size
    }

    class ViewHolder(@NonNull itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        internal val txtTitle: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.titleNote)
        internal val txtContent: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtNoteContent)
        internal val cvNote: CardView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.noteCardView)
        internal val view: View = itemView
    }
}
```

and this one is my mainactiviy.class:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private lateinit  var drawerLayout: DrawerLayout
    private lateinit  var navigationView: NavigationView
    private lateinit var menuDrawer: ImageView
    private lateinit var layoutDashboard : LinearLayout
    private lateinit var rvStore : RecyclerView
    private var endScale : Float = 1.8f
    private lateinit var adapter: NotesAdapter
    val titles: List<String> = listOf("First Note Title","Second Note Title","Third Note Title","Fourth Note Title")
    var content: List<String> = listOf("First Note Content Samples","Second Note Content Samples","Third Note Content Samples","Fourth Note Content Samples")

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        layoutDashboard = findViewById(R.id.linearMainActivity)
        rvStore = findViewById(R.id.rcViewStore)

        rvStore.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        rvStore.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(this,2)

        adapter = NotesAdapter(titles,content)
        rvStore.adapter = adapter
        rvStore.apply {
            rvStore.layoutManager = StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2,StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL)
            rvStore.adapter = adapter
        }

        Toast.makeText(this,"Array : " + titles.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }

    override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        return true
    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        if(drawerLayout.isDrawerVisible(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
        } else super.onBackPressed()
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe i'm missing something, but `this.titles = title` what is `title` here ? am i just not seeing it ?

Comment: Sorry, I've edited my code @a_local_nobody
It's in class constructor

Comment: i'm not sure if it makes a difference, it's just a bit strange that you have it twice, passing in as parameters and local fields too, are you sure you're referencing the right variables ? probably doesn't make a difference though

Comment: I usually use java tho, and this code is just me trying to write it in kotlin, but it turns out no text_view displayed .-. 
any idea about which one I should improve?
@a_local_nobody

Comment: in Java, we usually add a constructor with parameters like this
`public NotesAdapter(String titles, String Contents){}`

Comment: i don't suppose it matters. but you can use `NotesAdapter(val title:List<String>, val content:List<String>)` and probably get rid of the internal variables you have

Comment: @a_local_nobody still, textview didn't show up, but the cardview appears as much as the amount of data available

Comment: yeah i didn't think that would make a difference, i dont know why it doesn't show up, sorry

Comment: I see, no worries, thank you anyway @a_local_nobody

Comment: have you tried hardcoding the text view to always have text in the xml and see if that makes a difference ? perhaps something is wrong with your layout

Comment: @a_local_nobody Thanks dude, finally it works !!,
I've tried to make a simple item layout and it appears suddenly :)))))))))
LOL my previous layout is so complex  I guess --"

Comment: makes sense, nothing in code really seemed wrong, layouts are often times more complicated than the kotlin/java code